# Generating Coin flips using purrr

Tags: r, coin-flipping, purrr

Now I'm learning how to use purrr package in r, and thinking about how to generate 5 samples of each 1, 2, ..., 99, 100 coin flips.
My image is to create a list, that should look like..

```
[[1]]

[[1]]
[1] 1 0 1 0 0

[[2]]

[[1]]
[1] 1 0 0 0 1

[[2]]
[1] 0 1 0 1 1

[[3]]

[[1]]
[1] 0 1 1 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 1 0 0 0 1

[[3]]
[1] 0 1 1 1 1

..
```

Can anyone help me make this up?

Comment: `purrr::map(1:100, ~rerun(5, rbinom(., 1, 0.5)))` which is only slightly different than a full base R solution `lapply(1:100, function(x) rerun(5, rbinom(x, 1, 0.5)))`

Comment: `rerun` isn't base R so your "full base R solution" still has some purrr in it.

Answer (score 3):

You want the function `rerun` applied to each element of the vector `1:100` using the map function as follows

```
library(purrr)
1:100 %>% map(function(x) rerun(x, rbinom(5,1,.5)))
```

However, it is just as easy to use `replicate`, where the default for replicate is to produce a column wise array.

```
lapply(1:100, function(x) replicate(x,rbinom(5,1,0.5)))
```

Note that the base R expression is much faster in this case.

```
a <- function() 1:100 %>% map(function(x) rerun(x, rbinom(5,1,.5)))
b <- function() lapply(1:100, function(x) replicate(x,rbinom(5,1,0.5)))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(a(),b())

Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max  neval cld
  a() 96.89941 104.83822 117.10245 111.48309 120.28554 391.9411  100   b
  b() 16.88232  18.47104  23.22976  22.20549  26.31445  49.0042  100   a
```

**Edit** Regarding your question in the comments, if you are just interested in the law of large numbers representation, you could do as follows.

```
plot(1:100, do.call("c", lapply(b(), mean)),
 type= "l", xlab = "replications",
 ylab = "proportion of heads")
abline(h = .5)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this function does 5 flips for "1 coin", 100 times. What I want is, 5 flips for 1coin,  and then 5 flips for 2 coins, 5 flips for 3 coins, and so on.

Comment: Edited to address your clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If I were to make a histogram of the proportion of heads for each samples, how can I do it?

Comment: a histogram might not be the best way to represent the sampling?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're after:

```
lapply(1:100, function(x) replicate(x,rbinom(5,1,0.5),simplify = FALSE))
```